# How to get data from http://domain1.com localstorage to http://domain2.com express.js

Tags: angularjs, express, cross-domain, local-storage

how to get that data "52" from localhost:3000/ to localhost:8080 which is express.js. anyone? please help thank you
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBSF9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you control both domains? and can serve files from both? otherwise the browser won't let you.

If you do own both domains, you'd need to serve a file from the `domain1` and read about CORS to send the data to `domain2`.

Comment: yep i do own both domain. how am I able to send the data? thank you btw

Comment: You can only read local storage if the file is served by the same domain. So put that file there, get the data you need and send it using a post or get request. The specifics of the implementation would depend a lot on your code.